# dplyr equivalent to ddply in plyr diamonds example

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

ok, I'm trying to wrap my head around dplyr, using it instead of plyr. In my short time with R I've grown somewhat accustomed to ddply. I'm using a "simple" example  for how to use dplyr as opposed to ddply in plyr. Here goes: in the following:

```
t1.table <- ddply(diamonds, c("clarity", "cut"), "nrow")
```

I receive a summary table of counts of diamonds by clarity and cut. In dplyr, the simplest example I can come up with is:

```
diamonds %>% select(clarity, cut) %>% group_by(clarity, cut) %>%  
    summarise(count=n()) -> t2.table
```

which seems a bit more involved. Is there a better way to simplify this?   ~ thanks

Comment: I don't think you need the `select()` statement, since you're just counting rows?

Comment: Cool, so technically:   t2.table <- group_by(diamonds, clarity, cut) %>% summarise(nrow=n())    -or- better readability
t3.table <- diamonds %>% group_by(clarity, cut) %>% summarise(nrow=n())

Answer (score 6):

In the latest version of dplyr you can simplify that down to this:

```
diamonds %>% count(clarity, cut)
```

Or if you want to keep the column name 'nrow':

```
diamonds %>% count(clarity, cut) %>% rename(nrow = n)
```

If you've got plyr or rename loaded in your environment then you might need to prefix the rename:

```
diamonds %>% count(clarity, cut) %>% dplyr::rename(nrow = n)
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the help. I like this answer. Not quite as compact as the original ddply command, but a heck of a lot more readable.  (side note: answering a question is a pain, needs work)

```
    t3.table <- diamonds %>% group_by(clarity, cut) %>% summarise(nrow=n())
```