# dplyr equivalent to ddply in plyr: find one value from one column, then find this value's matching

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

My data looks like this:

```
aa <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4,5),Value=c(100,200,300,400,500),B=c(2,4,1,3,5))

A Value B
1   100 2
2   200 4
3   300 1
4   400 3
5   500 5
```

What I want to do is: for 1 in A, I find the value in B, which is 2. Then I find 2 in A. Lastly, I get 200 in Value based on 2 in A. How can I do it using ddply in plyr package and dplyr package?

I check same answers to [dplyr equivalent to ddply in plyr diamonds example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787435/dplyr-equivalent-to-ddply-in-plyr-diamonds-example) and others. But my problem looks a little bit more complex.

Comment: Do you want to do this for every value in `A` ?

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to do anything in *plyr* any more.

Comment: Maybe, something like `aa %>% mutate(new = Value[match(B, A)])` ?

Comment: Yeah. For every value in A, find the value in B, then go back to A to find the Value.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot.!